# Was the Lunar Topographic Camera ever used?

Tags: apollo-program, photography

From the *APOLLO  EXPERIENCE  REPORT  -
PHOTOGRAPHIC  EQUIPMENT AND   OPERATIONS
DURING    MANNED  SPACE-FLIGHT  PROGRAMS*
[NASA TN D-69](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19720025202/downloads/19720025202.pdf)

> However, more detailed photography was required  to evaluate the
> rougher sites proposed for later lunar-landing missions; consequently,
> the lunar topographic camera ( LTC ) (fig.  26) was introduced on
> the Apollo  13 mission. The LTC  is a 5-inch-format recurrence-type
> camera with an 18-inch-focal-length fixed-focus lens incorporating
> image-motion compensation and capable of continuous overlapping strip
> photography. The camera was designed for mounting in the command
> module hatch window and operation within the command module
> environment. This design approach considerably simplified the
> spacecraft interface and crew operational requirements, which were
> major factors in procuring this camera in the short time required and
> within the budgetary restrictions. Unfortunately, the LTC was not used
> for lunar photography  on the Apollo 13 mission, because the
> spacecraft did not attain lunar orbit. Reference 14 contains a
> detailed description of this equipment, and a photograph of the LTC
> system and the command module hatch mounting is shown in figure 27.

[image]

**The lunar topographic camera ( LTC ) could not be used on Apollo 13, was the LTC ever used during later Apollo missions?**

Answer (score 3):

The lunar topographic camera ( LTC ) was used on Apollo 14 and 16.

**Apollo 14 Mission Photography:**

> Hycon Lunar Topographic Camera.This electrically operated camera,
> which was carried aboard the CM, was a modified KA-7A Aerial
> Reconnaissance Camera, which, when used, was mounted in the crew
> access hatch window. A remote control box and interconnecting cable
> provided automatic mode or strip photography or manual mode for single
> frames. Variable Forward Motion Compensation (FMC) allowed for the
> spacecraft orbit motion. For each frame exposed, a small clock showing
> the day and time was simultaneously exposed to the side of the frame.
> This photography was intended to support the objective of obtaining
> high-resolution photography of future landing sites and areas of
> scientific interest. A camera malfunction partway into the mission
> caused the shutter to operate continually. This resulted from a
> transistor failure caused by a sliver of aluminum that became lodged
> and shorted the system on the shutter pulse switching circuit. Also,
> the lack of a continuous pulse, which activated the focal plane
> shutter, caused an intervalometer anomaly resulting in multiple
> exposure of the same scene. In addition, this same region of the film
> was overexposed approximately two stops.
>
> The lunar topographic camera (LTC) malfunctioned and only 193 usable
> photographs were recovered from the two rolls of 5-inch film.

[Source](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/missions/apollo/apollo_14/photography/)

**Apollo 16 Photographic Equipment**

> In addition, photography of the moon is accomplished with the lunar
> topographical camera (LTC).

[Source](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap16fj/02photoequip.html)

**From nasa spaceflight.com**

> NASA rebranded it "Lunar Topographic Camera" LTC.  It was originally
> to fly on the last three H-class missions: Apollo 13, 14 and 15. The
> first got its incident, on Apollo 14 the camera failed after 200
> pictures, and then Apollo 15 become a J-class with a SIM bay (and
> PanCam ? can't remember).
>
> Unlike PanCam it was mounted inside the Command Module, looking
> through the hatch window. One advantage: no EVA to retrieve the film.
> One issue: it was huge and took an entire astronaut seat when
> deployed.
>
> The camera then flew on Skylab and was called Earth Terrain Camera.
>
> It had pretty good performance, only slightly worse than PanCam.
>
> Ground resolution: according to "Spie and shuttles" book, 17 m to 30 m
> (55 ft to 100 ft)  on Skylab. And this already made the NRO a little
> nervous.
>
> Seems the infamous "Skylab Area 51 incident" happened with this camera
> ; not with the hand-held ones. And this probably is the reason why the NRO made a fuss about it !
>
> https://www.thespacereview.com/article/531/1/
>
> Around the Moon: 15 - 25 ft from a 60 nm orbit. 3 - 5 ft if the orbit
> was lowered to 8 nm (that's pretty low, even by lunar orbits standard !)

[Source](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=51893.0)

Some of the LTC photos on [collect space](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum9/HTML/003422.html)

[An example image](https://ia803106.us.archive.org/16/items/thirdpartyspacephotos_201808/AS14-80-10412-merged-C1-I0.jpg) from Apollo 14, 7216 * 6034 pixel, 124.57 MB, excellent quality.

A grand comparison of an LTC image to images by Chang'e and Kayguya/Selene:

[image]

Made by Paul of collect space.

**So the LTC was used on Apollo 14 and Skylab. Use on Apollo 16 is doubtful.**